# How to read OpenCV matrix data saved with std::ofstream?

Tags: c++, opencv

I saved a large matrix in OpenCV using simply std::ofstream, like so:

```
Mat someData;
std::ofstream fout("someFile");
fout << someData;
```

It stores the whole matrix in a file with `,` as the column separator and `;` as the row separator.

Is it possible to extract this data back into an OpenCV matrix again? How? Trying to do the converse with `std::ifstream` throws a "cannot bind" error.

Speed/efficiency/elegance is not a concern.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to load it from the file you wrote. You can first load the whole file into a long `string`. Then follow this thread [How to split a string in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/236129/2589776) to first split the whole `string` based on `;`, i.e. each of which stands for a row. After this, split it again based on `,`.

---

PS: it's much easier if you use `cv::FileStorage` while I/O matrices:

```
// write:
cv::Mat m = ...;
cv::FileStorage fs("myfile.txt", cv::FileStorage::WRITE);
fs << "mat" << m;
fs.release();

// read:
cv::Mat m2;
cv::FileStorage fs2("myfile.txt", cv::FileStorage::READ);
fs2["mat"] >> m2;
fs2.release();
```

Comment: Yes I know about `FileStorage` but I made the mistake of not using it. Now I'm stuck.

Comment: How would you say is it possible to do it, given the situation?

Comment: And then convert the parsed substrings into floats/ints? That's a long procedure! But that would work. Meanwhile, I removed the `,`s and the `;`s using usual find+replace and then read the values (using `ifstream`) into `myMat.at<float>(i,j)` inside a double loop. Does the job. Thank you.